# Speech Synthesis Utterance Language Voice not working on IOS/Safari Browsers including mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My spanish accent/lang voice works correctly on firefox/chrome, but when using my IOS/iphone or even Safari Desktop, the language defaults back to the english voice?  This is a problem because the english accent mispronounces the spanish language, therefore the app is useless on the phone.
Anyway to fix this issue??

Thank you.

```
const main = document.querySelector('main');
const textarea = document.getElementById('text');
const readBtn = document.getElementById('read');
const toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close');
const box= document.getElementById('box');



const data = [
  {
    image: './img/estados.jpg',
    text: "Soy de Estados Unidos",
    text2:"I am from the United States"
  },
  {
    image: './img/bano.jpg',
    text: "¿Dónde está el baño?",
    text2:"Where is the bathroom?"
  },
  {
    image: './img/english.jpg',
    text: "Disculpe, ¿entiende inglés?",
    text2:"Excuse me, do you understand English?"
  },
  {
    image: './img/police.jpg',
    text: "¿Dónde puedo encontrar a un policía?",
    text2:"Where can I find a policeman?"
  },
  {
    image: './img/help.jpg',
    text: 'Necesito ayuda!',
    text2:"I need help!"
  },
  {
    image: './img/ambulance.jpg',
    text: "Llame una ambulancia",
    text2:"Call an ambulance"
  },
  {
    image: './img/como.jpg',
    text: "¿Cómo está?",
    text2:"How are you?"
  },
  {
    image: './img/sorry.jpg',
    text: "Lo siento",
    text2:"I'm Sorry"
  },
  {
    image: './img/speak-slow.jpg',
    text: "¿Puede hablar más despacio, por favor?",
    text2:"Can you speak more slowly, please?"
  },
  {
    image: './img/gracias.jpg',
    text: 'Gracias',
    text2:"Thank you"
  },
  {
    image: './img/see-you-later.jpg',
    text: 'Nos vemos',
    text2:"See you later"
  },
  {
    image: './img/price.jpg',
    text: '¿Qué precio tiene…?',
    text2:"What is the price?"
  },
  {
    image: './img/phone.jpg',
    text: '¿Puedo tomar prestado tu teléfono?',
    text2:"May I borrow your phone"
  },
  {
    image: './img/morning.jpg',
    text: 'Buenos dias',
    text2:"Good Morning"
  },
  {
    image: './img/afternoon.jpg',
    text: 'Buenas tardes',
    text2:"Good Afternoon"
  },
  {
    image: './img/night.jpg',
    text: 'Buenas noches',
    text2:"Good Night"
  }
];


data.forEach(createBox);

//speechSynthesis.getVoices()
// Init speech synth
const message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
const lang = 'es-ES';
message.voiceURI = 'native';
message.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
message.rate = 0.8; // 0.1 to 10
message.pitch = 1; //0 to 2
message.lang = 'es-ES', 'Paulina';
message.voice = voicesList.find((voice) => voice.lang === 'es-ES', 'Paulina');


// Create speech boxes
function createBox(item) {
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  const { image, text, text2 } = item;

  box.classList.add('box');

  box.innerHTML = `
    <img src="${image}" alt="${text}" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="translate">${text}</div>
    </div>
    <p class="info">${text2}</p> 
  `;

  box.addEventListener('click', () => {
    setTextMessage(text);
    speakText();

    // Add active effect
    box.classList.add('active');
    setTimeout(() => box.classList.remove('active'), 800);
  });

  main.appendChild(box);
}



//Set text
function setTextMessage(text) {
 message.text = text;
}

// Speak text
function speakText() {
  speechSynthesis.speak(message);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Spanish Survival Guide</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>SPANISH SURVIVAL GUIDE</h1>
      <h3>Hover over boxes to translate & click on boxes to hear the phrases!</h3>
      <p>(Spanish voice accent currently not supported on safari browsers)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <main></main>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost there but there's an [event called the speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/voiceschanged_event) event that can be used to help populate a list of available voices. From here we can then select the desired voices.

I have created a proof of concept:

It should work on iOS Safari

```js
const data = [{
        image: './img/estados.jpg',
        text: "Soy de Estados Unidos",
        text2: "I am from the United States"
    },
    {
        image: './img/bano.jpg',
        text: "¿Dónde está el baño?",
        text2: "Where is the bathroom?"
    },
    {
        image: './img/english.jpg',
        text: "Disculpe, ¿entiende inglés?",
        text2: "Excuse me, do you understand English?"
    },
    {
        image: './img/police.jpg',
        text: "¿Dónde puedo encontrar a un policía?",
        text2: "Where can I find a policeman?"
    },
    {
        image: './img/help.jpg',
        text: 'Necesito ayuda!',
        text2: "I need help!"
    },
    {
        image: './img/ambulance.jpg',
        text: "Llame una ambulancia",
        text2: "Call an ambulance"
    },
    {
        image: './img/como.jpg',
        text: "¿Cómo está?",
        text2: "How are you?"
    },
    {
        image: './img/sorry.jpg',
        text: "Lo siento",
        text2: "I'm Sorry"
    },
    {
        image: './img/speak-slow.jpg',
        text: "¿Puede hablar más despacio, por favor?",
        text2: "Can you speak more slowly, please?"
    },
    {
        image: './img/gracias.jpg',
        text: 'Gracias',
        text2: "Thank you"
    },
    {
        image: './img/see-you-later.jpg',
        text: 'Nos vemos',
        text2: "See you later"
    },
    {
        image: './img/price.jpg',
        text: '¿Qué precio tiene…?',
        text2: "What is the price?"
    },
    {
        image: './img/phone.jpg',
        text: '¿Puedo tomar prestado tu teléfono?',
        text2: "May I borrow your phone"
    },
    {
        image: './img/morning.jpg',
        text: 'Buenos dias',
        text2: "Good Morning"
    },
    {
        image: './img/afternoon.jpg',
        text: 'Buenas tardes',
        text2: "Good Afternoon"
    },
    {
        image: './img/night.jpg',
        text: 'Buenas noches',
        text2: "Good Night"
    }
];

function rand(items) {
    // "|" for a kinda "int div"
    return items[items.length * Math.random() | 0];
}

//speechSynthesis.getVoices()
// Init speech synth
const message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var voices = [];

message.voiceURI = 'native';
message.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
message.rate = 0.8; // 0.1 to 10
message.pitch = 1; //0 to 2
message.lang = 'es-ES', 'Paulina';

function resetLanguage() {
    voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    console.log("Loaded Voices");
    message.voice = voices.find((voice) => voice.lang === 'es-ES', 'Paulina');
}
resetLanguage(); // Call the function on the devices

if (speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
    speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = resetLanguage;
}

function speakSpanish() {
    console.log("Using voice " + message.voice.name);
    message.text = rand(data).text;
    speechSynthesis.cancel(); // Reset any messages in the queue
    speechSynthesis.speak(message);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="speakSpanish()">
Speak
</button>
```